# How to find the child of a parent that is not indirect/ nested

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-traversal

I need to find a certain class and then find an input which is nested a number of elements below it. I need the target classes name as to append it.

I thought i could use .queryselector but it seems not. I cannot use the ID on the input.

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll('.pt-page.pt-subpage-current input');
var solve = input[0];

console.log(solve);
```

```html
<div class="pt-page pt-subpage-current"> /*only identifier*/
  <div class="container">
    <div class="question">
      <div class="input">
        <input name="school" type="text" id="schoolCode1" autocomplete="off">/*target*/
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought i could use query selector like above (I have been through many iterations) but no dice.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share the code with what you have attempted so far, so someone can help in debugging what the issue might be. What class are you trying to find, what sort of structure do you expect, etc.

Comment: Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) instead of `querySelector`.

Comment: _"I cannot use the ID on the input."_ Why not?

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of queryselectorall working in such a manner? I have updated the OP.

I can't use the ID as I am editing an existing app which cycles through selections and my code doesn't know when its moved on from one to another.

Comment: despite the typo (missing = in `class"question"`), your sample code seems to work ok. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nt6m5ey3/ . Have I misunderstood the issue here? Or have you not given us the full picture?

Comment: The code you posted works like a charm. There must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Use the direct descendant selector >
>
> ```
> $('#mainDiv > p:first')
> ```
>
> or even children()
>
> ```
> $('#mainDiv').children('p').first()
> ```